# Using flask-admin with flask blueprints

Tags: python, flask, pymongo, flask-admin

I want to set up a basic admin interface using flask-admin, and I want all of this to sit in a blueprint. Here's a minimal version my code:

```
#app.py
from flask import Flask
from bp import bp

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(bp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)


#bp.py
from flask import Blueprint, current_app
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.pymongo import ModelView
import pymongo

conn = pymongo.MongoClient()
bp = Blueprint('bp', __name__,
               template_folder='templates')

admin = Admin(current_app)
admin.add_view(ModelView(conn.my_db.my_collection))
```

When running `python app.py`, it crashes with `RuntimeError: working outside of application context`, because `admin` is in no way hooked (or whatever word is used to describe that) to `bp`.
Normally, one would write

```
@bp.route('/<page>')
def show(page): 
    pass
```

But I can't find the right decorator in the context of creating an `Admin` object. One thing I tried is to do `admin = Admin()` in `bp.py`, import `admin` in `app.py` and then `admin.app = app` in `app.py`. That works, but it feels like I'm splitting logic in several files, so I'm not really comfortable with that. What's the pythonic way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the actual app object to init the Flask admin Class. Current_app won't work. This call should be placed on app.py. Then on the blueprint you can use

`from app import admin`

Answer (score 0):

It work out in this way. just for your reference.

```
#YourApp/init.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_admin import Admin

db = SQLAlchemy()
admin = Admin(name='TuozhanOA', template_mode='bootstrap3')
def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(name)
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    db.init_app(app)
    admin.init_app(app)
    from YourApp.main.routes import main
    app.register_blueprint(main)
    from YourApp.adminbp.routes import adminbp, user_datastore
    app.register_blueprint(adminbp)
    security = Security(app, user_datastore)
    return app

#YourApp/adminbp/routes.py
from flask import render_template, Blueprint
from YourApp.models import User, Role
from YourApp import db, admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from wtforms.fields import PasswordField
from flask_admin.contrib.fileadmin import FileAdmin
import os.path as op

from flask_security import current_user, login_required, RoleMixin, Security, 
SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, UserMixin, utils

adminbp = Blueprint('adminbp', name)
admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session, category="Team"))
admin.add_view(ModelView(Role, db.session, category="Team"))

path = op.join(op.dirname(file), 'tuozhan')
admin.add_view(FileAdmin(path, '/static/tuozhan/', name='File Explore'))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Looking at code you submitted I suppose it could be a correct answer. Can you add some explanations for your code?